# changed src <audio> won't load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio

good morning, It's a guess game where a words is loaded dynamically with jquery from a dictionary/script, every word has a value and a definition ((example) "word":"read", definition:"the act of reading" ) , i am trying to add an audio to each word ((example) "word":"read", definition:"the act of reading", "Listen":"../read.mp3"). The problem is that the new audio (chosen randomly with the word) won't load in the place of the placeholder HTML audio after the page is loaded, Any suggestions?

if you want to see the original (https://codepen.io/Armania/pen/YdxbGY)

```
    function hideWords() {// set for secret word
  var sword = dictionary[random].word;
  var definition = dictionary[random].definition;
  var Listen = dictionary[random].Listen;
  $("p.secret").html(""); // deleting any content in the secret word display
  $(".secret-word").html(sword); // adding the secret word.
  $(".definition").html("<p> " + definition + "</p>"); // adding the definition hint.
  $("#mp3Source").attr({ "src": Listen});//adding audio
  audio.get().load();
  audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();
  var i=0; // create variable for while lop
  while (i < sword.length){ // check while loop against number of letters in secret word
    var idk = sword.charAt(i); // get the current letter and add to variable
    $("p.secret").append("<span class='secretLetter' value='" + idk + "'><i class='fas fa-question'></i></span>");// add secret letter to list
    i++; // count up for while loop
  }
}
```

that goes here

```
<p class="secret"></p>
    <div class=" bg-light" style="width:66%; margin:auto; padding:1rem;">
        <h4>Word Definition:</h4>
        <div class="definition"> 
      <p><span>Noun</span> <span>so-un-ds</span> llorem ipsum text for the definintion. may have multiple definitions included, each seperated as a paragraph.</p></div>
        <p><span>Noun</span> <span>so-un-ds</span> llorem ipsum text for the definintion. may have multiple definitions included, each seperated as a paragraph.</p></div>
        <div class="Listen"><audio id="audio" controls="controls">
          <source id="mp3Source" src="../1/sounds/_57sleep.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source>
        </audio>
    </div>
```

dictionary/script

```
var dictionary = [
  {
    "word": "read",
    "definition": "the act of reading",
    "Listen":"../../1/sounds/read.mp3",
  },
```

Comment: `src="../1/sounds/_57sleep.mp3"` is not the same as `"../../1/sounds/read.mp3"` they're not targetting the same folder, since you are using the same folder, you should change only the name of the mp3 file not even the extension.

Comment: actually they are in different folders, but that not the issue here, is it?

Comment: Can you show your static full path for the JS and HTML files and Audio files

Comment: actually i changed the code, removed the html div and used appendTo `$("<audio></audio>").attr({
    'controls':'controls',
    'src':Listen,
    'volume':1,
}).appendTo(".secret");
`

Comment: but other problems are appearing, it's the first time i deal with jquery, and it keep spitting loading errors, maybe i'll delete the whole thing

Comment: the funny thing is, it's not consistent, if I reload the page, it works four or five time alright, then from no where an error (something is not defined)

Comment: Ok can you provide a live version so we can debug it

Comment: thank you @SaymoinSam for your help. however i found another pen with vanilla javascript https://codepen.io/koFT/pen/oYMgXK

Comment: I don't get it, were you looking for an audio solution or a vanilla JS hangman game?!

Comment: No, I was l looking for a vanilla JS hangman game so i can add audio to it

Comment: Ah ok, happy coding